# Consulta foreach anidado, no logro hacerlo funcionar

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, registro

Estoy intentando traer de una base de datos los registros correspondientes a 'medida' y 'precio'.
Base de Datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En razon de estos arrays:

```
array(5) {
  ["accion"]=>
  string(9) "act_plato"
  ["categoria_id"]=>
  string(3) "142"
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "640"
  ["index"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["datos"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["plt"]=>
    array(1) {
      [2]=>
      array(6) {
        ["es"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["nombre"]=>
          string(10) "Plato Tres"
          ["texto"]=>
          string(22) "Descripcion plato tres"
        }
        ["en"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["nombre"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["texto"]=>
          string(0) ""
        }
        ["precios"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(2) {
            ["medida"]=>
            string(14) "Porcion Grande"
            ["precio"]=>
            string(2) "25"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(2) {
            ["medida"]=>
            string(13) "Porcion Chica"
            ["precio"]=>
            string(2) "18"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

$arrPrecios = $platos[$index + 1]['precios'];

$cp = $dao->query("select * from carta_platos where id=$id")->fetch();
$id_plato = $cp['id'];
$pp = $dao->query("select * from carta_precios where carta_platos_id=$id_plato")->fetchAll();

foreach ($pp as $ppid) {

      $precioId = $ppid['id'];
      //echo $precioId."\n";

      foreach ($arrPrecios as $values) { 
            //$precioId = $value['id'];
            $precioMedida = $values['medida'];
            $precioPrecio = $values['precio'];

            $sqlPrecio = "UPDATE carta_precios SET medida='$precioMedida',precio='$precioPrecio',carta_platos_id='$id_plato',estado='0' WHERE id='$precioId' AND carta_platos_id='$id_plato'";

            $dao->exec($sqlPrecio);
            }
        }
```

Cada vez que actualizo el precio o la medida de un plato me guarda solo el ultimo  en todos los registros de la base de datos correspondiente a ese plato.
Por ejemplo, si yo guardara esta edicion, en la base de datos se actualizaria la tabla "carta_precios" con id 1 y 2 con el mismo registro ("Porcion Chica", "15"). Se entiende?
Gracias por su ayuda desde ya.

Comment: Deberías actualizar por `id` y no por `carta_platos_id`, porque este no es único. Aunque también puedes hacerlo con `medida`.

Answer (score 0):

espero sirva de algo esta opción:...

```
<?php
$datos = array();

$datos['platos'] = 
   array(
      array(
         'id' => "1",
         'medida' => 'Porcion Grande',
         'precio' => "25"
      ),
      array(
         'id' => '2',
         'medida' => 'Porcion Chica',
         'precio' => "15"
      )
   );

foreach ($datos['platos'] as $array => $value) {
   /**
    * No creo que sea necesari hacer select en cada UPDATE que quieras realizar,
    * pero lo dejo aqui en caso de que lo requieras
   */
   echo "SELECT * FROM carta_precios WHERE carta_platos_id = " . $value['id'];

   echo "
         UPDATE carta_precios
         SET medida='". $value['medida'] ."', 
               precio='". $value['precio'] ."',
               carta_platos_id='id_plato',
               estado='0' 
         WHERE id='". $value['id'] ."'
         AND carta_platos_id='id_plato'
      ";

   //Los dejé impresos para que los revises antes de ejecutarlos.
} ?>
```

Saludos